# HTML/JS Displaying a bar chart with totals between billions and minuses

Tags: javascript, html, charts

My highest and lowest values are: 19002678404.19 and -23873.

I need to somehow display these in a bar chart graph a long with some other values, I understand this is probably not advisable but what would be the best approach to doing this?

I have tried using jsCharts and Morris but because the values have such a big difference, the formatting  does not work.

What I tried with Morris:

```
     <script>
 new Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-example',
  data: [
 { y: 'Name1', a: -11367},{ y: 'Name2', a: 2792463.6},{ y: 'Name3', a: 59337.23},{ y: 'Name4', a: 7053.1},{ y: 'Name5', a: 19002678404.19},{ y: 'Name6', a: -23873},{ y: 'Name7', a: 59998},{ y: 'Name8', a: 44393},{ y: 'Name9', a: 23543},{ y: 'Name10', a: 19315},{ y: 'Name11', a: -10489},{ y: 'Name12', a: -10971},{ y: 'Name13', a: -12015},{ y: 'Name14', a: -13873},{ y: 'Name15', a: -7381},{ y: 'Name16', a: 23118},{ y: 'Name17', a: 80098},{ y: 'Name18', a: 150549},{ y: 'Name19', a: 6658017.1721709},{ y: 'Name20', a: 9772},{ y: 'Name21', a: 20122},{ y: 'Name22', a: -1967},{ y: 'Name23', a: 156},{ y: 'Name24', a: 135258},{ y: 'Name25', a: 0},{ y: 'Name26', a: 8598},{ y: 'Name27', a: 2339},{ y: 'Name28', a: 140621},{ y: 'Name29', a: 534},{ y: 'Name30', a: 415}
],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a'],
  labels: ['Total']
});
</script>
```

As seen in this jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/am6thnq3/

Comment: You should try to enforce a maximum scale. **EDIT:** check here: http://jsfiddle.net/kyewygqw/

Comment: Better value here: http://jsfiddle.net/kyewygqw/1/ using `ymax: 120000`